# Unable to load class error with sonarqube in gitlab

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, gitlab, sonarqube-scan, gitlab-ci-runner

I've been having troubles with getting gitlab to send jobs to sonarqube. I have installed the sonarqube plugin and added my gitlab user token to the sonarqube server. In my gitlab-ci.yml I run the following command:

```
- git config --global user.email "$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL"
- git config --global user.name "$GITLAB_USER_NAME"
- cd /opt
- wget -q https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-3.2.0.1227-linux.zip
- unzip -qq sonar-scanner-cli-3.2.0.1227-linux.zip
- cd /builds/my_user_name/my_project/backend
- /opt/sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227-linux/bin/sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.host.url=http://34.230.xx.xx -Dsonar.projectKey=$CI_PROJECT_NAME.develop -Dsonar.projectVersion=$CI_COMMIT_SHA -Dsonar.gitlab.url=https://www.gitlab.com -Dsonar.gitlab.project_id=$CI_PROJECT_ID -Dsonar.gitlab.user_token=$SONAR_PLUGIN_TOKEN -Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha=$CI_COMMIT_SHA -Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.sources=.
```

The error I get is the following. I get this error both with using the npm sonarqube-scanner as well.  Does anyone know what is going on?

```
05:12:15.795 DEBUG:   * GitLab 3.0.0 (gitlab)
05:12:16.171 INFO: Process project properties
05:12:16.184 DEBUG: Process project properties (done) | time=13ms
05:12:16.199 INFO: Load project repositories
05:12:16.227 DEBUG: GET 404 http://34.230.xx.xx/batch/project.protobuf?key=my_key_here&issues_mode=true | time=25ms
05:12:16.229 DEBUG: Project repository not available - continuing without it
05:12:16.234 WARN: Project doesn't exist on the server. All issues will be marked as 'new'.
05:12:16.235 INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=36ms
05:12:16.314 INFO: Scanning only changed files
05:12:16.317 INFO: Execute project builders
05:12:16.999 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
05:12:17.006 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
05:12:17.007 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
05:12:17.008 INFO: Total time: 4.682s
05:12:17.050 INFO: Final Memory: 11M/104M
05:12:17.051 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
05:12:17.052 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectLock
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:265)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:120)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:133)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:111)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.DefaultInputModuleHierarchy
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your [Sonar plugins versions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix), compared to your SonarQube version.

As in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/jRA4x6oWioU/UhcXv2yFBQAJ), you would (for instance) be running SonarQube 7.1 with extensions made for SonarQube 7.0 (Branch, Developer).

The [OP Coherent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2232620/coherent) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335571/unable-to-load-class-error-with-sonarqube-in-gitlab/51335741#comment89655070_51335741) using:

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 80:9000 -p 9092:9092 \
 -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=x 
 -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=y 
 -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://mydatabase-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/sonar sonarqube:7.0
```

[Tibor Blenessy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578706/tibor-blenessy) [adds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335571/unable-to-load-class-error-with-sonarqube-in-gitlab/51335741#comment90259633_51335741)

> Try to remove `-Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview`, this option is no longer supported.

Comment: Oh thanks for the suggestion. I downgraded to v. 7.0 by creating a new docker container and used the sonar-gitlab-plugin v 3.0 which supports 7 and I still get the same error.

Comment: @Coherent Maybe there is a plugin which is not at a compatible version.

Comment: Thanks, what's weird is that it actually was a base docker that I spun up and the only plugin I installed was gitlab (although there were several installed by default in the 7.0- uninstalling them didn't seem to change the error). `docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 80:9000 -p 9092:9092 -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=x -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=y -e SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://mydatabase-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/sonar sonarqube:7.0` I'm wondering if my sonar-scanner command is wrong.

Comment: Try to remove `-Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview ` , this option is no longer supported